# Why python code is unable to run inside a EKS pod container?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have EKS cluster setup, where in a pod I'm downloading s3 bucket objects. I have added service account with role of s3 full access and KMS. But I'm unable to download.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Things I have tried:

**Exec into pod and run python code `python3 s3_downloads.py`**

**In this s3 botocore config adding access key and secret key works well.
`s3 = boto3.resource('s3', access-key,secret-key)`**

**Making buckets public.**

Even though I have added proper role attached to service account,im unable to download. Is any configs am i missng ? Any help would really be appreaciated.

Comment: Have you setup "IAM Roles for Service Accounts"? That is needed first.

Comment: you can find the steps you need to take to enable service account to access AWS resources [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html)

Comment: yes, i have set "IAM Roles for Service Accounts" @Jonas

Comment: When i use same SA to other pod, it works. But this s3_download is not working.@RezaNasiri

Comment: It works well with other buckets. only one bucket is not working. Am i missing something ? @Jonas

Comment: @RezaNasiri please check above comment

Comment: If it works with other buckets and only this one gives you access denied error, I would check resource policies for you bucket and CMK that is used to encrypt it to make sure there is no explicit denies there

Comment: This gives as "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied". @RezaNasiri.

Comment: works when i add secret key and access key into my code. fails when i add service acc.

Comment: Upgrading python it helped. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that I was missing the session creation. Here is my original code:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
```

The fixed code:

```
session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.client('s3')
```

I was executing this code on a Pod running on a EKS cluster and the missing line was preventing me to use the ServiceAccount role I had defined for this deployment.

Details about boto3 and sessions management on this post https://ben11kehoe.medium.com/boto3-sessions-and-why-you-should-use-them-9b094eb5ca8e